# Protecting directory in asp.net is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to place pages in separate directories. I have set the web.config like this

```
           <location path="AdminPanel">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>

            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

but when access the directory in the browers it lists all the pages in directory structure. What I am ddoing wrong?

Comment: Is directory browsing disabled on your site? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I read this before but then why is this option?? and why would this not work if the directorybrowsing is not disabled in the IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET security can only block requests made by ASP.NET, so it can only block the content within the directory, not block you from accessing the directory structure itself.  You need to disable directory browsing as @Claudio recommended to fix that problem, and your security will block access to the individual files in the folder.

Comment: if i host on commercial server then can I do it there?

Comment: Yes.  That was the point of the feature.  Comm. Hosted most likely doesn't have directory browsing enabled.